# React render compoents by string (comming from server)

Tags: react-router

I have a list of components coming from the server with JSON which is inside a variable.

I want to call the component dynamically.

```
listOfcomponents.map(x => {
    <Route path={x.slug}  component={x.component} />;//(SomeComponent)
});
```

this is the component

```
export const SomeComponent = (props) => {
     return <div>Some Component</div>
}
```

The server is deciding about the component that will be called.
How do I let Route have a dynamic component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible! What you're looking for is called: Dynamic imports. And it rocks!

I've had a similar case where I needed to render components dynamically. However the biggest challenge was to keep my routes organized. This is how I implemented this logic:

```
async function getComponent(route) {
   const {default: module} = await import(`../${route}`)
   const element = document.createElement('div')
   element.innerHTML = module.render()
   return element
}
```

Comment: If you want to take this to the next level, look into Lazyloading components. Really interesting!